# DynamoDB query contains on a list parameter

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

In my DynamoDB table I have objects that contain a list of tags ("tags", SS). I want do scan all items where they have a tag that contains a certain string.

I tried to do something like this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
    {
        //{ ":v_Search", new AttributeValue { S = searchString } },
        { ":v_SearchTags", new AttributeValue { SS = new []{searchString }.ToList() } }
    };
var scanRequest = string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)? new ScanRequest(Table): new ScanRequest
{
    TableName = Table,
    ExpressionAttributeValues = dictionary,
    FilterExpression = "contains(tags, :v_SearchTags)",
    ProjectionExpression = "tags"
};
```

But that just returns nothing. Both v_search and v_searchtags don't work. Even though the values are listed in the table

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work like that, you have to do a filter expression like

```
FilterExpression = "contains(tags, :x) AND contains(tags, :y)"
```

Where :x and :y are plain old strings.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html

Note:

> The operand must be a String if the attribute specified by path is a String. If the attribute specified by path is a Set, the operand must be the set's **element type**.

Comment: how can this be applied to a list of objects instead of a list of plain strings?

Comment: it will only work if the objects have a list of string tags, or you can build a query from strings contained in the object.